# What is a Sunrise dispute?

Tags: domain-registration, legal, domain-registrar

What is a Sunrise dispute?

I've skimmed over [this page](https://www.lawinsider.com/dictionary/sunrise-dispute-resolution-policy) that defines the SDRP (Sunrise Dispute Resolution Policy), but I still don't feel like I know what I'm looking at.

I see lots of documentation referencing specific disputes on domain registrars' sites relating to this entity called Sunrise.

- Who are Sunrise?
- Why are there so many disputes?
- Who should be concerned and want to read up on these?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't think that "Sunrise" is an entity.

I believe that, in the context of domain names, a "Sunrise dispute" occurs when a new TLD/CCTLD/subdomain becomes available and multiple parties want to lay claim to the same domain name in the new space - ie "Sunrise" here means the creation of a new set of domains.

I've found https://www.name.com/blog/sunrise-landrush which talks about this in some depth.

Answer (score 2):

In addition to David Go's answer, an example is the 2023 release of direct .au domains e.g. example.au, where there were specific criteria about who could apply for the domain during the lead up to release.  There was also a process if both example.com.au and example.net.au were already registered and the *both* wanted example.au.

The details of how it was resolved aren't important to your question, but the process that both exmple.com.au and example.net.au registrants would have had to go through is an example of how a sunrise dispute might be resolved.